# How can I get values in a javascript object?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a `javascript` object in `.aspx` page which have some parameters whose values needed to be fetched from `.aspx` fields **on page load**.

This is the `javascript` object-

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
trackingObject = {text1:"",text2:"",Date1:""};</script>
```

The values of `text1`,`text2`,`Date1` needs to replaced from `.aspx` page fields(like from `textbox`).

How can I achieve this with the help of `RegisterStartupScript` or any other easy and alternative method?

Comment: If you use `Object` (notice the capital `O`), you have the possibility of messing up a lot of code. `Object` is specifically the built-in name for the object constructor. And your code is in the global scope, meaning it will override the built-in `Object`

Comment: You have to get a reference to the DOM elements and then read their `value` properties (assuming they are `input` elements).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, assign Id for those controls, then

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var text1Text = document.getElementById('text1Id').value;
    var text2Text = document.getElementById('text2Id').value;
    var date1Text = document.getElementById('date1Id').value;
    var obj = {text1:text1Text, text2:text2Text, Date1:date1Text };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" runat="server"/>
   // you can get this text box value by jquery like this
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var txt1val = $('#<%= txt1.ClientID %>').val();
    </script>

 <script type='text/javascript'>
    var text1Text = $('#<%= yourAspTextbox1ID.ClientID %>').val();
    var text2Text = $('#<%= yourAspTextbox2ID.ClientID %>').val();
    var text3Text = $('#<%= yourAspTextbox3ID.ClientID %>').val();
    var obj = { text1: text1Text, text2: text2Text, Date1: text3Text};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do this:

### HTML

```
<input type="text" /><br />
<input type="text" /><br />
<input type="text" /><br />

<input type="button" value="Show Obj"/>
```

### Javascript

```
$("input[type='button']").on("click", function () {
    var values = [];

    $("input[type='text']").each(function () {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });

    trackingObject = {    
        text1: values[0],
        text2: values[1],
        Date1: values[2]
    };

    alert(JSON.stringify(trackingObject, null, 4));
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kFZTd/1)

Comment: javascript is not called on butten click. values needed to be stored on page load. Thats why I mentioned about RegisterStartupScript.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("test", "<script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function(){trackingObject = {text1:'" + txtbox1.Text + "',text2:'" + txtbox2.Text + "',Date1:'" + txtDate.Text + "'};}) ;</script>");
```